# How to use the Paypal API in a similar way to Kickstarter

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I've had a look at the preapproval API which looks kind of like what I want but not quite.

I need to mimic the way Kickstarter works fairly closely; users are sent to the Paypal site where they sign in and agree a payment then on a certain date the payment either gets taken from their account or, if some conditions aren't met, nothing happens. I know Paypal are 'funny' about some uses, but actual goods and services are for sale so I think it should be OK.

I need many people to be able to contribute to one larger payment; I don't know if there's a way of setting up a something like this inside of Paypal itself or if all the logic should be kept separately and then the Paypal payment triggered on a certain date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered two questions on quora related to this that you might find interesting about PayPal's recommended approach for crowdfunding projects like this:

http://www.quora.com/PayPal/I-want-to-use-Paypal-for-my-self-hosted-crowdfund-campaign-but-I-heard-they-might-close-my-account-if-theres-too-much-money-coming-in-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this

[http://www.quora.com/PayPal/Is-paypal-better-for-crowdfunding-than-amazon-payments-why-or-why-not/answer/Praveen-Alavilli?**snids**=55404046#ans1382191](http://www.quora.com/PayPal/Is-paypal-better-for-crowdfunding-than-amazon-payments-why-or-why-not/answer/Praveen-Alavilli?__snids__=55404046#ans1382191)

Let me know if you have any questions that I can help with.